# Can't run simple Hibernate application

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jdbc

i'm sorry if you will consider this post as duplicated, but i couldn't find and answer for my problem. Maybe you can help me) Thanks.

```
"
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@536f2a7e'
***Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.javabrains.UserDetails
    at*** org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1627)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at org.javabrains.Main.main(Main.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

***Main.java***

```
package org.javabrains;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


/**
 * Created by roysez on 26.03.2017.
 */
public class Main {


public static void main(final String[] args)  throws Exception{
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("Sergiy");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

***hibernate.cfg.xml***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
                "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
                "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name='connection.driver_class'>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name='connection.url'>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
    <property name='connection.username'>root</property>
    <property name='connection.password'>sergio161098</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name='connection.pool_size'>1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name='dialect'>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name='show_sql'>true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <!-- Mapping files -->

    <mapping class="org.javabrains.UserDetails"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

***UserDetails.java***

```
package org.javabrains;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * Created by roysez on 26.03.2017.
 */
@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

I don't know what to do, try all solutions but any of them can't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending to use the JPA API, I think you should change line 3 of `UserDetails.java`:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
```

to use JPA annotations:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

[Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-entity) says `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` does *not* replace `javax.persistence.Entity`, it just allows to configure additional features.

Comment: thanks,but i then i hav another error) table exist)
caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernate.userdetails' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put all correct annotations: @Table,@Column,@GeneratedValue etc. in UserDetails.java.
And not forget to have some schema on MySQL server.

And if you are using Hibernate 5 you must use `javax.persistence.` package for annotations